# Result looks differently based on browser

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core
I'm doing some tutorials, and have a weird experience.

When I run it on Chrome, site.css file doesn't seem to work. However, on Firefox, everything looks fine.
* site.css doesn't work on Chrome, but works on firefox or Incognito window of Chrome.

Environment:
ASP.NET CORE 3.0
template: Web application

here's my github: https://github.com/matthiasjk5/ContosCrafts

I had this experience on Spring Boot as well. Can you give me some tips?

[on left, chrome, looks site.css doesn't load. On right, firefox, looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKaem.jpg)

Comment: If it works in incognito mode in Chrome, it sounds like it could be an extension or something to do with your cache. Could you try clearing your cache and make sure you don't have any unwanted extensions? You could also open the Chrome Developer Tools, go to the Network tab, and see what is happening to the `site.css` file through there.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse! after removing cache on chrome, it is working on chrome now :)
just curious why cache affects loading css file.